# Multiple create-react-app apps with node js and express server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, create-react-app

I have the following configuration on my localhost.

```
const express = require('express');
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

// Config
const { routes } = require('./config.json');

const app = express();

for (route of routes) {
  app.use(route.route,
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: route.address,
      pathRewrite: (path, req) => {
        return path.split('/').slice(2).join('/');
      }
    })
  );
}

app.listen(80, () => {
  console.log('Proxy listening on port 80');
})
```

then config.json for all the routes

```
{
  "routes": [
    {
      "route": "/project",
      "address": "http://localhost:3000"
    },
    {
      "route": "/project2",
      "address": "http://localhost:3001"
    }
  ]
}
```

in the `project` folder I have create-react-app in `client`. When I run npm start within this folder, accessing `http://localhost:3000` works as expected. When I try to access `http://localhost/project` it will reverse proxy to the correct folder but it's not serving JS or CSS.

I have looked through several forums and tutorials but can't make this work.

Could anyone help?

Comment: Do you have two different `express` apps that serve to different `React` applications or both are served from a single `express` server? Your configuration file indicates that it is the former but you're trying to access both under the same port (3000)?

Comment: one express server. One app is on port 3000 and the other 3001

Comment: If you're running on two different ports, then you're running two different servers. Unless I am not understanding something. Maybe you mean two different routes?

Comment: hmm. Confused :-) all the code above is the only code I have so far

Comment: Not sure I follow, you're listening in port `80` but trying to access things on port `3000`?

Comment: Perhaps what you need is something like https://arpitonline.com/2017/02/09/serving-multiple-reactjs-apps-with-express/ and not `http-proxy-middleware`